# Why do I get this error when putting models.CASCATE?

Tags: python, django

This is my models.py content:

```
    content = models.TextField()
    seen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey('Users', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def _str_(self):
        return self.content

class Users(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    online = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def _str_(self):
        return self.name

    pass
```

and I am getting this error when trying to put " models.CASCATE " in on_delete module:

````
  File "/workspace/testjson/App/backend/chat/chatApp/models.py", line 8, in Messages
    user = models.ForeignKey('Users', on_delete=models.CASCATE)
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'CASCATE'```
Could someone explain me why I am getting this error? Thanks <3
````

Comment: There is typo error. Its `models.CASCADE`, replace it in your code and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

It's `models.CASCADE`. replace T with D